# Spark 2.2 fails with more memory or workers, succeeds with very little memory and few workers

Tags: scala, apache-spark, memory, hadoop-yarn

We have a Spark 2.2 job writte in Scala running in a YARN cluster that does the following:

1. Read several thousand small compressed parquet files (~15kb each) into two dataframes
2. ​Join the dataframes on one column
3. Foldleft over all columns to clean some data
4. Drop duplicates
5. Write result dataframe to parquet

The following configuration​ fails via java.lang.OutOfMemory java heap space:

- ​--conf spark.yarn.am.memory=4g
- **--conf spark.executor.memory=20g**
- --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1g
- --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
- --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true
- --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=5
- --conf spark.executor.cores=4
- --conf spark.network.timeout=2000

However, this job works reliably if we remove **spark.executor.memory** entirely. This gives each executor 1g of ram.

This job also fails if we do any of the following:

- Increase executors
- Increase default parallelism or spark.sql.shuffle.partitions

Can anyone help me understand why more memory and more executors leads to failed jobs due to OutOfMemory? ​

​

Answer (score 0):

Manually setting these parameters disables [dynamic allocation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation). Try leaving it alone, since it is recommended for beginners. It's also useful for experimentation before you can fine tune cluster size in a PROD setting.

Throwing more memory/executors at Spark seems like a good idea, but in your case it probably caused extra shuffles and/or decreased HDFS I/O throughput. This [article](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/), while slightly dated and geared towards Cloudera users, explains how to tune parallelism by right-sizing executors.

Comment: Dynamic allocation adjusts executor memory as well? I thought it was just the number of executors, each having the configured number of cores and memory. In any case, I'm running a test right now with 2 executors each having 30gb of ram and it is incredibly slow compared to 1gb of ram per executor. Is this the decreased throughput you were mentioning? How does that even happen?